# React using fetch returns undefined after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, refresh

When I try to get information from the API and retrieve it into a scroll list, at first retrieval is successful, but when the page is refreshed, an error message is received under inspect:

> "Uncaught TypeError: response is null".

How can this issue be resolved?
The API I'm using: https://opentdb.com/api_category.php

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://opentdb.com";
const GetApiData =  ({ url }) => {
const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
const [error, setError] = useState("");
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async() => {
    await axios
      .get(url)
      .then((res) => setResponse(res.data))
      // console.log('cccc')
      .catch((err) => setError(err))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  };
  fetchData();
}, [url]);

return { response, error, loading };
```

Here I call it, the problem is with the line :

```
<FieldOptions options={response.trivia_categories} label="Category" />
```

```
const { response, error, loading } = GetApiData({ url: "/api_category.php" });
    return (
    
    <form >
      <FieldOptions options={response.trivia_categories} label="Category" />
      <FieldOptions options={difficultyOptions} label="Difficulty" />
      <FieldOptions options={typeOptions} label="Type" />
      <TextField id="filled-basic" label="How many questions?" variant="outlined" type="number" onChange={handleChange}/>
      <Box mt={3} width="100%">
        <Button fullWidth variant="contained" type="submit">
          Get Started
        </Button>
      </Box>

    </form>
    
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you're initializing response to null in your useState hook?

`const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);`

If you try to access the response variable before it gets set by your API fetch, it will be the value of null.

You can try initializing it to a different value such as an empty object. This might work depending on how you access the variable when your component initially renders.

`const [response, setResponse] = useState({});`

Or, you can check if response is not null before accessing it.

```
if (response !== null) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help
tried it and also `const [response, setResponse] = useState([]); `
and also the condition , and it is still the same error.